# is there any dtd/xsd for mobileconfig

Tags: java, ios, iphone

I am trying to generate .mobileconfig file using java (same way the iPhone Config Utility does).

Is there any xsd/dtd for the same?

Thanks you in advance.

Regards

Dipankaj

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about XSD, but this may help you:

http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf

So you can create one, if you really need it.